# Getting location with Android Google Map v2

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

I can't get my locayion. It always crashes. I checked everything. Can anyone please help me find my location?

```
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isGooglePlay()){
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        setupmapifneeded();
    }
}

private void setupmapifneeded() {
    if(map==null){

         map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


    }if(map!=null){

         map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

         LocationManager mlm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
         Criteria c = new Criteria();

         String provider = mlm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

         if(provider == null){

             onProviderDisabled(provider);
         }

         Location mylocation = mlm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
         if(mylocation != null){
             onLocationChanged(mylocation);
         }   
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private boolean isGooglePlay(){
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        return true;

    }else{
        ((Dialog)GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10)).show();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "nai", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location mylocation) {
    double lat = mylocation.getLatitude();
    double longi = mylocation.getLongitude();
    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat,longi);

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information such as, what exactly is the error message shown, and what were you trying to do precisely.

Comment: Just a few pointers: Use proper English as much as you can. Use your shift key to capitalize where appropriate (the pronoun "I" is always capitalized). Don't use ellipses (...) everywhere. Don't abbreviate excessively (prblm, pls, plz). Make sure your code is readable. Don't post functions that are not relevant to your problem (stubs).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true)

this will get your location on the map automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`Location location = map.getMyLocation();`